# Get absolute xpath of all text nodes under node

Tags: python, selenium, xpath

I have an xpath which is made by adding 3 strings

```
path_prefix='(.//tr|.//div[not(ancestor::div)][not(descendant::tr)])[3]'
r1=u'Company  (Name in which such subsidiary conducts business if other than corporate name):  '
path=path=path_prefix+"//*[text()="+"'"+r1+"'"+"]"
```

When I run this path on browser, it works perfectly fine. But when I try to run this on selenium using execute_javascript it gives a null element.

```
stg="var element=document.evaluate("+'"'+path+'"'+",document, null, XPathResult.FIRST_ORDERED_NODE_TYPE, null).singleNodeValue;return element.getBoundingClientRect()"
driver.execute_script(str(stg))
```

Also, I checked when I run the code, my stg element looks like this. (extra '\' gets added, but still it works perfectly in browser)

```
stg='var element=document.evaluate("(.//tr|.//div[not(ancestor::div)][not(descendant::tr)])[3]//*[text()=\'Company  (Name in which such subsidiary conducts business if other than corporate name):  \']",document, null, XPathResult.FIRST_ORDERED_NODE_TYPE, null).singleNodeValue;return element.getBoundingClientRect()'
```

Edit: (Comment from OP)

*the main problem is. i want to extract all the text nodes present in the html page and their xpaths . xpath should be starting from html/*/*/... . Is there any better way or any library that already exists.*

Comment: Share your HTML code.

Comment: is the url public ?

Comment: urll -https://www.sec.gov/Archives/edgar/data/84129/000104746919002567/a2238552zex-21.htm

Comment: the main problem is. i want to extract all the text nodes present in the html page and their xpaths . xpath should be starting from html/*/*/... .
Is there any better way or any library that already exists.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to get the absolute xpaths of all the textnodes in the html, I would suggest using the Javascript will will be much faster and easy. You just have to ignore the "↵" in your script.

Here is the Javascript solution implemented in python.

Note: The array output will have "text - absolutexpath" pair.

```
  # this is the custom javascript developed to get the absolute xpaths for all 
  # textnodes under given element using TreeWalker
  jsFunction = """window.getAbsoluteXpathsUnder =function(el){
  var nText ='';
  var aPath ='';
  var elm="";
  var tNode, aPaths=[], walk=document.createTreeWalker(el,NodeFilter.SHOW_TEXT,null,false);
  while(tNode=walk.nextNode()){
        nText = tNode.textContent;
        if (nText.trim()!=""){
        aPath='';
        elm = tNode.parentNode;
        while (elm.tagName!='HTML'){ aPath = elm.tagName + "/" +aPath; elm=elm.parentNode;}
         aPaths.push(nText + " - HTML/" + aPath);
        }
  }
  return aPaths;
};"""
# Run the Javascript function
driver.execute_script(jsFunction)
# get the all text node absolute xpaths under first "div table"
aXpaths = driver.execute_script("return getAbsoluteXpathsUnder(arguments[0])",driver.find_elements_by_css_selector('div table')[0])
print(aXpaths)
```

And here is the **output**.
[image]

You have 3 such tables in the page you might have to call `aXpaths = driver.execute_script("return getAbsoluteXpathsUnder(arguments[0])",ele)` 3 times or use a loop.

Comment: Try this solution and let me know how it goes.